# Do we still need to do DEFINITION LOAD in ECC 6 EHP4+

Tags: abap, sap-erp

I am adapting RM_FM_EXCEL_TO_INTERNAL_TAB to my needs and I saw the following code:

```
"Get TAB-sign for separation of fields
CLASS cl_abap_char_utilities DEFINITION LOAD.
ld_separator = cl_abap_char_utilities=>horizontal_tab.
```

Can you confirm that there is absolutely no need to do the definition load any more, I assume this is some ancient legacy code? I never load class before using static methods or attributes and it appears to work.

Comment: trying to get a SAP stack page started, check it out http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41621/sap-systems-applications-and-products

Comment: Done, been following this for a while. Not sure about the momentum though :\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As always, I'd recommend to take the [official documentation](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_702/en/abapclass_interface_load.htm) as a reference:

> The variants of the statements CLASS and INTERFACE with the addition LOAD are obsolete. ABAP Compiler ignores these statements.